# File previewers for PDF and Docx

Tags: java, pdf, preview, docx, doc

I would like to have a preview of a `.pdf,` `.docx` or `.doc` file inside a `JDialog`. But I'm unable to find previewers that allow nesting of such previews inside a Swing application. Alternatively are there any previewers that can transform such files into `.html` and then display them in a `TextPane`.

Fidelity isn't that much of an issue as is embedding and ease of use. Also I don't require one tool to be able to preview all types of files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a tough one because of the formats you're dealing with.  You might want to try ImageMagik for PDF -> image format for display in your TextPane.  If that works well enough for PDFs, then you could use JOD Converter or Docmosis to get from Doc -> PDF then ImageMagick again for a display image.  JODConverter and Docmosis are based on OpenOffice which can do pretty rough html / xhtml output as another option for display.  The latest version of OpenOffice can read docx also, meaning all your bases are covered, and if fidelity is not too big a deal as you've indciated, then JODConverter/Docmosis and ImageMagick might be a combo you can use.

Comment: Which way we can configure Docmosis project in java application

Comment: I suggest sneding them a support email asking this question.